# Creating a SQL trigger to update tables when entering data in a view

Tags: postgresql

If I have this setup:

```
CREATE TABLE category(
  category_id    serial PRIMARY KEY,
  category_name  text UNIQUE NOT NULL  -- must be UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE parts (
  part_id        serial PRIMARY KEY,
  category_id    int REFERENCES product,
  part_name      text
);

CREATE VIEW partview AS
SELECT com.part_id, cat.category_name, com.part_name
FROM   parts com
LEFT   JOIN category cat USING (category_id);
```

How do I create a trigger so that when I insert data into the view, the source tables are updated?
I tried this... but it doesn't work :(

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_view_func() 
RETURNS trigger as

$func$
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO parts (category_name)
        select (select category_id from category where category_name = category.category_name) 
        RETURNING category_id as id
        into new.componentid;

        return new;
    END
$func$ language plpgsql;

create trigger insert_view_trig
INSTEAD of insert on partview 
for each row execute procedure insert_view_func();
```

Comment: How does it not work? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: Are you not going to insert values for `part_id` and `part_name`?

Comment: What's with `componentid`?

Answer (score 0):

The big issue with view insert triggers on non-simple views is you do not know what is be inserted. 
In this case that could be Category or Parts or both. Your trigger has to handle both. Here that is not much a issue here:

```
create or replace function insert_view_func() 
  returns trigger 
  language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    insert into category (category_name)  values(new.category_name)
      on conflict do nothing; 

    insert into parts (category_id, part_name)
         select category_id, new.part_name 
           from category 
          where category_name = new.category_name;  

    return new;
end ;
$$ ;
```

That, however, is not the major issue here. Your data model setup a 1:M relationship between Category:Parts.
Not a problem if that is what you really want, but it does open a potential problem. Since the Part_Name is not unique it opens
the possibility of multiple parts with the same name (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3b46818f2a17686c7927b233c1dd75df)), but each associated to a separate category. 
This could become quite confusing. To avoid this you may want to consider a M:M relationship and creating a resolution table. The other option would be modifying the trigger function to check for existing part_name. Better yet make Part_Name unique.